# Installing an older version of a ros package by source

Tags: asus-xtion-pro-live, ubuntu, rospackage, ubuntu-quantal, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used to run version 1.8.9 of openni_camera, and I'd like to revert back to an older version of it. The source is found [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/tree/85bdfab75541d9029bb7b58d60d9fabc87145c93).

This is actually a commit between versions 1.8.8 and 1.8.9. Does anyone know how I can go about installing this package through source?

I've previously installed `openni_camera` as a deb package, and have uninstalled it using `sudo apt-get --purge remove ros-groovy-openni-camera`. What I've tried so far is putting the source folder into my catkin workspace (`~/catkin_ws/src`), and using `catkin_make` in `~/catkin_ws`, but I'm faced with an error:

```
$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/andrew/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/andrew/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/andrew/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/andrew/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/andrew/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/andrew/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.71
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - openni_camera
-- ~~  - servo
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'openni_camera'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(openni_camera)
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/extras.cmake:47 (message):
  Could not run dynamic reconfigure file 'cfg/OpenNI.cfg':
  /home/andrew/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh: 10: exec:
  /home/andrew/catkin_ws/src/openni_camera/cfg/OpenNI.cfg: Permission denied
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  openni_camera/CMakeLists.txt:11 (generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on ROS Groovy, and using an Asus Xtion Pro Live. Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75586/installing-an-older-version-of-a-ros-package-by-source/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2013-08-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`dynamic_reconfigure` requires `cfg` file to be executable. So doing:

```
$ chmod a+x cfg/OpenNI.cfg
```

should be enough to make it compile.

It might be not very good idea to use commits between releases though, since there can be unfixed bugs. So I hope you know what you are doing.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-08-29**:
I took up your advice and just checked out the previous version. Thanks!